# How can I create reliable flask-SQLAlchemy interactions with server-side-events?

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask app that is functioning to expectations, and I am now trying to add a message notification section to my page.  The difficulty I am having is that the database changes I am trying to rely upon do not seem to be updating in a timely fashion.

The html code is elementary:

```
    <ul id="out" cols="85" rows="14">

    </ul><br><br>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var ul = document.getElementById("out");
    var eventSource = new EventSource("/stream_game_channel");
    eventSource.onmessage = function(e) {
        ul.innerHTML += e.data + '<br>';
    }
    </script>
```

Here is the msg write code that the second user is executing.  I know the code block is run because the redis trigger is properly invoked:

```
        msg_join = Messages(game_id=game_id[0],
                            type="gameStart",
                            msg_from=current_user.username,
                            msg_to="Everyone",
                            message=f'{current_user.username} has requested to join.')

        db.session.add(msg_join)
        db.session.commit()

        channel = str(game_id[0]).zfill(5) + 'startGame'
        session['channel'] = channel

        date_time = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
        redisChannel.set(channel, date_time)
```

Here is the flask stream code, which is correctly triggered by a new redis time, but when I pull the list of messages, the new message the the second user has added is not yet accessible:

```
@games.route('/stream_game_channel')
def stream_game_channel():
    @stream_with_context
    def eventStream():
        channel = session.get('channel')
        game_id = int(left(channel, 5))
        cnt = 0
        while cnt < 1000:
            print(f'cnt = 0 process running from: {current_user.username}')
            time.sleep(1)
            ntime = redisChannel.get(channel)
            if cnt == 0:
                msgs = db.session.query(Messages).filter(Messages.game_id == game_id)
                msg_list = [i.message for i in msgs]
                cnt += 1
                ltime = ntime
                lmsg_list = msg_list
                for i in msg_list:
                    yield "data: {}\n\n".format(i)
            elif ntime != ltime:
                print(f'cnt > 0 process running from: {current_user.username}')
                time.sleep(3)
                msgs = db.session.query(Messages).filter(Messages.game_id == game_id)
                msg_list = [i.message for i in msgs]
                new_messages = # need to write this code still
                ltime = ntime
                cnt += 1
                yield "data: {}\n\n".format(msg_list[len(msg_list)-len(lmsg_list)])
    return Response(eventStream(), mimetype="text/event-stream")
```

The syntactic error that I am running into is that the msg_list is exactly the same length (i.e the pushed new message does not get written when i expect it to).  Strangely, the second user's session appears to be accessing this information because its stream correctly reflects the addition.

I am using an Amazon RDS MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to utilize a db.session.commit() before my db.session.query(Messages).filter(...) even where no writes were pending.  This enabled an immediate read from a different user session, and my code commenced to react to the change in message list length properly.